# HttpClient how to convert nested json and map to model in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have nested JSON object and I want to store in the Array `private categoryModule: CategoryModel[] = [];` with Angular 7 `HttpClient`.

JSON object:

```
[
  {
    id: 1, name: 'Mr. Nice', descriptio: 'dasdad', image: "sada", product: [
      { id: 0, name: 'Milos', descriptio: "sdada", number: 1, image: 'ssad' },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2, name: 'Misko', descriptio: 'dasdad', image: "sada", product: [
      { id: 0, name: 'Milos', descriptio: "sdada", number: 1, image: 'ssad' },
      { id: 1, name: 'Somi', descriptio: "haha", number: 1, image: 'haha' }
    ]
  }
]
```

My model ProductModel is :

```js
export class ProductModel  {

  constructor(
    public id:number,
    public name: string, 
    public description: string, 
    public numberOfProduct: number, 
    public image: string) {}
}
```

My model CategoryModel:

```js
export class CategoryModel  {

  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public image: string;
  public products: ProductModel[] ;


  constructor(
      name: string, 
      desciption: string, 
      image: string = null, 
      products: ProductModel[], 
      id: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desciption;
    this.image = image;
    this.products = products;
  }
}
```

This is my service for get method :

```
  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getCategory(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]>(this.cateogryUrl).pipe(
    /* map(products => {
        return Object.values(products)

      }),*/
      catchError(this.handleError('getProduct', []))
    )
  }
```

This is my code component for storing data in Array.

```
 getCagegoryFromServer() {
    this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory().subscribe((category :CategoryModel[]) => {

      this.categoryModule = category;
      console.log(this.categoryModule[0].products[0] + "milos car");
    })
  }
```

I have problem  in my `categoryModule` Array because `products` is `undefined`. Obviously  `products` not initialized. Do any know how to fix that?

Comment: `products` is not initialized because it's named `product` in the JSON. Similarly, your description is named `descriptio`. Fix the JSON. Also, change your classes to interfaces: HttpClient will not create an instance of your classes. If you really need actual instances of your classes, then you need to map the json explictly, and create new instances explicitly.

Comment: Voting to close for typo.

Comment: OK, you can give me some examples, to I see how to fix that?

Comment: Well, just fix the JSON data: instead of `product`, use `products`. Instead of `descriptio`, use `description`. What is unclear?

Comment: You could use interfaces only (if classes are not required) so it will be "mapped" by itself.

Comment: @Antoniossss, can you please give an example how to work with interfaces or point me to a link if there is any?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to map your json response to model classes, then you need to map the json response to the model classes:

```
getCategory(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
  return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]>(this.cateogryUrl).pipe(
    map(categories => categories.map(categoryJson => new CategoryModel(
      categoryJson.name, 
      categoryJson.descriptio, 
      categoryJson.image, 
      categoryJson.product.map(productJson => new ProductModel(
        productJson.id,
        productJson.name, 
        productJson.descriptio, 
        productJson.number, 
        productJson.image
      )),
      categoryJson.id
    ))),
    catchError(this.handleError('getProduct', []))
  )
}
```

This being said, it's unclear why you are mapping to javascript classes, as your classes don't seem to have any methods associated with them. As pointed out by a few comments, you could just make use of the returned json directly, and use typescript interfaces to provide IntelliSense / error checking.

If you are going to stick with javascript classes, using a single options argument in the class constructor, rather than individual property arguments, would make things easier.

For example

```
export class CategoryModel  {

  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public image: string;
  public products: ProductModel[] ;


  constructor(args: {
    name: string, 
    desciptio: string, 
    image: string = null, 
    product: {
      id: number,
      name: string, 
      descriptio: string, 
      number: number, 
      image: string
    }[], 
    id: number
  }) {
    this.id = args.id;
    this.name = args.name;
    this.description = args.desciptio;
    this.image = args.image;
    this.products = args.product.map(json => new ProductModel(json));
  }
}
```

This would simplify the `getCategory()` method to:

```
getCategory(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
  return this.http.get<CategoryModel[]>(this.cateogryUrl).pipe(
    map(categories => categories.map(categoryJson => new CategoryModel(categoryJson))),
    catchError(this.handleError('getProduct', []))
  )
}
```

Comment: In categories.map() I have an error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'CategoryModel'